# Fat row, multipage pdf creation with Reportlab (i.e. for invoice, bill etc)

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, invoice

I would like to make an invoice with reportlab that has multiple pages, but all the tables should be of same height, and any page that has lesser number of data will have a fat row that pulls the "total" row to the bottom. Much like this: http://www.invoiceberry.com/img/homepage/free_invoice_templates/screenshot_invoiceberry_invoice_template_1.jpg

It would be great if someone gives me a direction on how these kinds of tables can be achieved with Reportlab? Or if there's any online resource on it.

Comment: First: show your code.